# TemplateDoesNotExist when base template is in root folder

Tags: python, django, templates

I have the following directories:

Project

- templates <-- base.html located here
- users <-- App

-- users/templates <-- profile.html located here

profile.html extends base.html. And when I'm trying to access it:

```
return render_to_response('profile.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm getting TemplateDoesNotExist exception:

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: profile.html

> Django tried loading these templates, in this order: Using loader
>   django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: Using loader
>   django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>   ...lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/profile.html
>   (File does not exist)
>   ...lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/profile.html
>   (File does not exist) ...users/templates/profile.html (File exists)

Answer (score 2):

Change your `templates` directory structure, That is `app/templates/template.html` to `app/templates/app/template.html` by adding an `app` directory inside the `app/templates` directory.

```
Project
|-- users
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- templates
|       `-- users
|           `-- profile.html
|-- templates
    `-- base.html
```